# Reference dll from resources

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, reference

I need to reference in my project a dll library that contains a UI component. So I literally drag and drop it in solution explorer tab, then I add this code on top of XAML page:

```
xmlns:Banner="clr-namespace:(the namespace);assembly=(name of the dll file without extension)"
```

When I try to compile the solution, it says that the assembly was not found.
The problem could be build action of the dll? I tried setting the property to "copy always" and the build action to "resource", but with no luck.

Comment: Is the dll blocked? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/p/unblockingdownloadedfile.aspx

Comment: At first it was, then I unblocked it but same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check these, common step i do when facing problem with third-party dll reference:

1. Have you added reference to that dll from your project? if no then add it, if yes check the following
2. in solution explorer > references, is the reference to that dll marked with warning sign (yellow triangle with exclamation mark in the middle)? if no, that means this is not a common problem, maybe the dll itself problematic or what i'm not sure in this case. But if yes, it means that the dll no more exist in the folder location where you reference it. Copy the dll to that folder location or remove that reference from project and add again pointing to folder location where the dll actually exist.

ps: Hope this help. And sorry if you already did all that before posting the question, all i know what you did is drag and drop the dll to solution explorer.

**UPDATE :**

After your comment i get what you are after actually. As far as i know, to be able to use dll in code you need to add it as reference in project. Thats why i suggested above steps, to make sure that the dll appears fine in references list in solution explorer. Drag and drop dll or any file to solution explorer only make it included in the project. And including file in project doesn't make it usable from code (except .cs/.vb file). CMIIW.

Comment: Well, adding the recerence through project properties window works. So my question is: in the way I described in the post above, shouldn't be the same? (so without manually adding the reference in project properties tab)

Comment: updated my answer. As far as i know including a dll file to project (either by drag & drop or manual copy paste then include) is not enough to make it usable from your code.

Comment: I was not sure as well, but I just followed steps included in a document with the library. I'm going to contact the company in order to solve this issue. Thank you

Comment: I see, so it was the doc that leads you to do drag and drop. never mind, hope they gives you the best solution.